# How to insert new-line, between lines of a text file, if two consecutive lines have different first fields?

Tags: awk, sed, zsh

I'm producing a text file (in zsh on MacOS) containing pathnames and their associated checksums.

```
# finding all the files in a directory and checksumming them
find . -type f -exec md5 -r {} \; > file1.txt

# sorting the file by the first field (checksum)
LC_ALL=C sort -k 1,1 file1.txt > file2.txt

# using awk to keep all/only lines with duplicated first/checksum fields
# (i.e., duplicate files in the directory)
# I found this awk on the net and it works
# yes, the input file is read twice
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++;next}(a[$1] > 1)' file2.txt file2.txt > file3.txt
```

You can produce a sample file by executing the three commands above on the directory of your choice.  Here's a short sample:

```
0c1fe4bd35f263f1eb3944c3bd6036e7 ./photoshop-conversion/pano-work-02.psb
0c1fe4bd35f263f1eb3944c3bd6036e7 ./photoshop-conversion1/pano-work-02.psb
0d47004b36229ed68a7c1d820bc7bfa3 ./photoshop-conversion3/pano-03.psb
0d47004b36229ed68a7c1d820bc7bfa3 ./photoshop-conversion4/pano-03.psb
0d47004b36229ed68a7c1d820bc7bfa3 ./photoshop-conversion5/pano-03.psb
0d47004b36229ed68a7c1d820bc7bfa3 ./photoshop-conversion6/pano-03.psb
101e5579acc8389796d0155461ef5183 ./photoshop-conversion5/pano-01.psb
101e5579acc8389796d0155461ef5183 ./photoshop-conversion6/pano-01.psb
```

At this point, file3.txt lists all the checksum & pathnames (that have duplicated checksums), but there is no white-space (blank lines).  I want to add blank lines between the groupings of 2 or more lines with duplicate first fields (in order to make the listing human-readable).  This can be done either by another discreet stage (producing file4.txt from file3.txt) or by modifying the prior awk stage to insert new-lines between lines that have different first fields (as file3.txt is produced).

This would do something like:

```
if (first-field-of-current-line ^= first-field-of-next-line)
then insert new-line after end-of-current-line
```

This would result (in the sample above) inserting a blank line between the 2nd and 3rd lines and between the 6th and 7th lines.

I don't care how it's done -- awk, sed, grep -- so long as it's available for zsh in MacOS.

Extra points if you can count how many groups there are (i.e., how many new-lines get inserted).

I've tried to change the awk line herein, but I don't understand it well enough not to break it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The temporary files seem ugly and unnecessary.

```
find . -type f -exec md5 -r {} + |
LC_ALL=C sort -k 1,1 |
awk 'a[$1]++ { if(prev) print rs prev;
    prev=""; print; rs="\n";
    if(a[$1] == 2) n++; next }
  { prev=$0 }
  END { print "=== total", n }' >file.txt
```

Because the input is already sorted, you only need one pass through the Awk script. We keep track of the previous line in `prev` and if we see another line with the same prefix, we print that too.

In some more detail, `a` keeps track of whether we have seen this MD5 before. If we have, print `prev` and then make sure we don't print it again if we see additional instances of the same MD5. The variable `rs` will be empty originally, but contain a newline after we have printed the first group (so we avoid printing an empty line before the first group, but print one before each subsequent group). Finally, we increment `n` if this was a new group.

If we fall through to the next unconditional action, that means we are looking at a new unique MD5. Keep track of this line in `prev` in case it would turn out to be a duplicate when the next line is read in.

Finally, in the `END` block, print how many groups we counted.

As a minor additional efficiency hack, I changed the `\;` to `+` which causes `find -exec` to behave like `xargs`.

The addition of the total at the end is slightly ugly, too; perhaps instead simply `grep -cxF '' file.txt` and add 1.

Comment: Thank you.  This answer works and answers the question.  I'm going to mark this answer as Accepted because it's concise and comprehensible to me (probably because it closely resembles how I was already approaching this problem).

Answer (score 0):

One option is to do almost everything in `zsh`. This uses a fairly conventional shell loop, which can sometimes be easier to understand:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

# create array with md5 values for all regular files
#   - **/*: recursive file glob
#   - (.): limit to regular files
#   - (f): split by newlines
#   - (o): sort the lines
typeset -a md5sums=(${(fo)"$(md5 -r **/*(.))"})

count=0
inGroup=false
for entry in $md5sums ''; do
    # split line using equals expansion, get sum
    sum=${${=entry}[1]}
    if [[ $sum == $priorSum ]]; then
        inGroup=true
        print $priorEntry
    elif $inGroup; then
        inGroup=false
        print $priorEntry
        print
        ((++count))
    fi
    priorEntry=$entry
    priorSum=$sum
done
print "Count: $count"
```

This script should do everything in the process you outlined, from generating the `md5` values to creating the final output. It uses some `zsh`-isms that may not be familiar; most are documented in the `zshexpn` man page and in the [online guide](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion).

Comment: Thank you.  This answer works and answers the question.  I'm not going to mark it as Accepted, however, because I like the answer by tripleee better.